# How to transfer files from one system to another in a LAN can be done automatically as scheduled?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking, nas

The Automation file Back up Storage System in a LAN over a Different Operating system can be Scheduled and Done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up a NFS (Network File System) server and you can schedule a backup to this NFS server over the LAN network.

You can schedule backups from any OS to a NFS server without any problems.